# 二分探索木と配列について

Tags: c, windows

配列`data[i]`に格納されている要素値を配列`heap[i]`へ順次格納し、配列`heap`の要素値を入れ替える関数`upheap()`の部分と。また`main`関数内のコメントアウトを削除し、`heap[0]`の値が `heap[size-1]`に、`size`が`size-1`に置き換える。課題の条件を満たすように、置き換えられたれた `heap[0]`の値を入れ替える関数`downheap()`の部分だけがどのようにしたらいいのかわかりませんでした。わかる方どうかお願いします。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void printarray(int heap[], int size);
void swap(int heap[], int i, int j);
void upheap(int heap[], int i);
void downheap(int heap[], int i, int size);
int main(void){
 int data[] = {8, 98, 87, 36, 35, 54, 11, 33, 6, 79}, size = 10;
 int *heap, i;
 heap = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*size); 
 for(i = 0; i < size; i++){ 
 heap[i] = data[i];
 upheap(heap, i); 
 }
 printarray(heap, size);
 // heap[0] = heap[--size]; 
 // downheap(heap, 0, size);
 // printarray(heap, size);
 return 0;
}
void printarray(int heap[], int size){
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
 printf("%2d%c", heap[i], i == size-1 ? '\n': ' '); 
}
void swap(int heap[], int i, int j){
 int tmp = heap[i];
 heap[i] = heap[j]; 
 heap[j] = tmp; 
}
void upheap(int heap[], int i){

}
void downheap(int heap[], int i, int size){

}
```

Comment: `upheap()` も分からないのか、`downheap()` だけが分からないのか文章が分かりづらい気がします。 / 質問すること自体は問題ありませんが、何らかの課題であるなら課題の提出者に直接質問した方が解決が早い場合もあります。

Comment: 次の投稿はあなたの質問の回答になりますか？ [二分探索木のプログラム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/85614/%e4%ba%8c%e5%88%86%e6%8e%a2%e7%b4%a2%e6%9c%a8%e3%81%ae%e3%83%97%e3%83%ad%e3%82%b0%e3%83%a9%e3%83%a0)